# 'Are there' and 'How many'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm confused about questions with 'Are there' and 'How many'.

First:

I have two questions and two answers during the interview from my textbook.

> **'Are there many offices?'** - There's one head office and there are four other offices in the UK.
> **‘How many offices are there?’** - ‘There are three in Britain and two in the United States.’

The questions are different but the answers are almoust the same! Why?

Second situation:

> **‘How many** offices are there?’ - ‘There are three in Britain and two in the United States.’
>
> **'How many** sites are there in the UK?' - 'There's the head office, the other offices, the store branches and our warehouse.'

The answers are different but the questions are the same! Why?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with English? The same situation is possible in all other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is the case of interview so the answers provided are superfluous! Just to give more (or say better) information. The answers, if you see from a grammarian's view, could be much shorter and precise.

> 'Are there many offices?' - No, not many. 
>   How many officers are there? - There are five officers.

But then, when you reply *No, not many.* the **obvious** question will be *Okay, how many?* and you'll have to reply *five*. And since the scene is of the interview, every information is important and thus, where are those five officers is also mentioned with their location, I think.

Same with scene two:

> How many offices are there?’ - There are five offices 
>   How many sites are there in the UK? - There are [number] sites in the UK. I'd also upvote for the answer given there for this question. Since 'sites' also refer to 'type' of offices/premises, it's better to answer that way than giving the number.

Again, it's an interview and the obvious questions respectively will be *where are those offices* and *where are those sites* and to avoid multiple questions, I guess, all the information is included in **one smart answer**.

Now take **the answers given and let's guess their questions**

> How many offices are there in the UK? - There's one head office and there are four other offices in the UK. 
>   How many offices are there worldwide? - There are three in Britain and two in the United States.